# Built in sql keyword/function to find the difference between 2 varchar(max) values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Something like Select **KeyWord**(Col1, Col2) from [table]. I am using MS SQL Server. 2016, but the version doesn't matter.

I want to find all indexes or values of different characters in col2 that are not in col1.

Example data: Select Keyword(Name, SecondName) from [table]

Bob | Tom - this would return the inverted intersection in a set, so from the example, the output should be 2 rows. Bb and Tm.

Comment: what Database do you use?

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: Add some sample data and the expected based on that sample data (_formatted_ text please, [no screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Comment: This post shows no effort or research on your part.

Comment: Add required result for operation between 'test' and '321tset' either :)

Comment: Your requirements are incomplete.  What if `col2 = `T1e2s3t`?  What would the output be?  What if `col1='Test Two`?